# Play framework (2.4) docker container fails to connect to Cassandra database, which runs on the same host

Tags: playframework, docker, cassandra

I have:
`CentOS 7` running on `Vbox (Win host)`, 
`Cassandra` installation: `3.3.0`,
`Play` application to implement REST, and WebSocket Apis.

In preparation for `AWS` deployment, created `Docker` image for `Play` application.
Intention is to have `Cassandra` hosted on `AWS` as well, not necessarily through `Docker`. Trying to test `Play` docker locally. Application comes up and available, but fails on connecting to database. A few things understood, but not the whole picture. Outside of docker, `Play` was connecting to `Cassandra` through `127.0.0.1:9042`. I guess now, Cassandra host information needs to be delivered into container via run --add-host, and possibly changes needed to `rpc_address`, and 'listen_address' from `cassandra.yaml`, both were having defaulted 'localhost' ? Tried many combinations of settings with no success, always the same error, sample:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.nohostavailableexception: All host(s) tried to query failed (tried: cassandra/127.0.0.1:9042) ...
```

I was wondering if there is a procedure to follow to make it working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address connectivity issue by passing `--net=host` to the run commend. As following:

`sudo docker run --net=host -e DB_PORT=9042 -e DB_HOSTS=127.0.0.1 -e DB_KEYSPACE=mykeyspace -p 9000:9000 myplay-image`

For my testing purpose, having the host and container to share the network space is acceptable. Certainly,Play app has a logic to recognize and read ENV variables: `DB_PORT`, `DB_HOSTS`, `DB_KEYSPACE`.